# Why is R reported to use much more memory by Windows than by itself?

Tags: r, windows, windows-10

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

On a 32G system, I got this error when creating a distance matrix:

```
df <- remove_duplicates_quanteda(dfm, df)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.3 Gb
```

Looking inside my enviroment, there is little reason for concern:

```
print(object.size(x = lapply(ls(), get)), units = "Mb")
96.5 Mb
```

However, Windows reports the following figures:
[image]
What is the reason for this difference?  Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Could it be that you want to allocate a matrix with each column/row (vector) about 1.3GB? For how many objects you are calculate the distance matrix?

Comment: What does a similar exercise with `pryr::object_size()` report?

Comment: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.3 Gb` does mean R has been happily allocating memory until there was no more memory available. It reports how much more memory would be needed for the next allocation (within the function you have called). Even if you have 1.3 GB more memory, it might not be sufficient for the next allocation. Distance matrices can be huge. You cannot judge if there is reason for concern based on what's in your global environment. You have to consider the memory demand of the operation you want to do.

Comment: <cont> You can either calculate that or (preferably) do benchmarks with increasing input sizes.

Comment: Aaronp: There was only one object, and the code worked perfectly after a restart of Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Hadley put it pretty simple in Advanced R:

> This number won’t agree with the amount of memory reported by your
>   operating system for a number of reasons:
>
> 1. It only includes objects created by R, not the R interpreter itself.
> 2. Both R and the operating system are lazy: they won’t reclaim memory
>      until it’s actually needed. R might be holding on to memory because
>      the OS hasn’t yet asked for it back.
> 3. R counts the memory occupied by objects but there may be gaps due to
>      deleted objects. This problem is known as memory fragmentation.

For more information see the Section about [Memory](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But this isn't merely about reporting and reclaiming allocated memory as it actually had the consequence that a 1.3G vector could not be allocated. For various reasons (vanity included) I am hesitent to constantly close Visual Studio/reboot.